# In function, receive "Internal error in `df_slice()`: Columns must match the data frame size."

Tags: r

I'm trying to run filter() on the cur_data() of (potentially) grouped data

The following works fine:

```
lookAhead = 2
colnm = sym(glue("maxCloseGainPctNext{lookAhead}"))

p = dailyDataFinal %>% 
    summarise( xxx=nrow(filter(cur_data(), {{colnm}}>0)) )
```

But when I add:

```
p = dailyDataFinal %>% 
    summarise(n  = n(), 
        xxx = nrow(filter(cur_data(), {{colnm}}>0))
    )
```

I get:

```
Error: Problem with `summarise()` column `nPos(2)`.
i `xxx = nrow(filter(cur_data(), maxCloseGainPctNext2 > 0))`.
x Internal error in `df_slice()`: Columns must match the data frame size.
```

In fact **either** of the summarise lines is fine by themselves, it's just the combination that breaks it, even though the output from eack is a 1x1 tibble.

I'm at a total loss to understand what that message means.

Input data is a basic tibble:

```
> dailyDataFinal
# A tibble: 10,003 x 30
   date       gspc.adjusted gspc.close gspc.high gspc.low gspc.open gspc.volume gspc.DailyGainPct maxCloseGainPctNext2
   <date>             <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>             <dbl>                <dbl>
 1 1982-04-20          115.       115.      117.     115.      116.    54610000            -1.08                 1.52 
 2 1982-04-21          116.       116.      116.     115.      115.    57820000             0.243                2.52 
 3 1982-04-22          117.       117.      117.     116.      116.    64470000             1.27                 1.77 
 4 1982-04-23          119.       119.      119.     117.      118.    71840000             1.24                 0.523
 5 1982-04-26          119.       119.      119.     118.      119.    60500000             0.523               -1.06 
 6 1982-04-27          118        118       119.     118.      119.    56480000            -1.06                -0.627
 7 1982-04-28          117.       117.      118.     117.      118.    50530000            -0.627               -0.699
 8 1982-04-29          116.       116.      117.     116.      116.    51330000            -0.955                0.586
 9 1982-04-30          116.       116.      117.     116.      116.    48200000             0.258                0.876
10 1982-05-03          117.       117.      117.     116.      116.    46490000             0.326                0.728
# ... with 9,993 more rows, and 21 more variables: maxHighGainPctNext2 <dbl>, minCloseGainPctNext2 <dbl>,
#   minLowGainPctNext2 <dbl>, maxCloseGainPctNext5 <dbl>, maxHighGainPctNext5 <dbl>, minCloseGainPctNext5 <dbl>,
#   minLowGainPctNext5 <dbl>, maxCloseGainPctNext10 <dbl>, maxHighGainPctNext10 <dbl>, minCloseGainPctNext10 <dbl>,
#   minLowGainPctNext10 <dbl>, maxCloseGainPctNext20 <dbl>, maxHighGainPctNext20 <dbl>, minCloseGainPctNext20 <dbl>,
#   minLowGainPctNext20 <dbl>, range <dbl>, openProp <dbl>, closeProp <dbl>, openLevel <fct>, closeLevel <fct>,
#   candleType <glue>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to help if you produce a small but reproducible example for us to test the issue. Based on your description I have created a similar example and  the code works for me.

Code outside the function.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)

lookAhead = 2
colnm = sym(glue("abc{lookAhead}"))

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(abc1 = rnorm(5), abc2 = rnorm(5))


df %>% 
  summarise(xxx=nrow(filter(cur_data(), {{colnm}}>0)))

#  xxx
#1   2
```

Code inside the function.

```
fsumm = function(data, lookAhead) {
  colnm = sym(glue("abc{lookAhead}") )
  data %>%
    drop_na({{colnm}} ) %>%
    summarise("nPos({{lookAhead}})" := nrow(filter(cur_data(), {{colnm}}>0)),  
    )   
}
fsumm(df, 2)

#  nPos(2)
#1       2
```

---

For the updated question using `n := n()` is not correct since `n` is not a variable. If you put `n = n()` at the end of `summarise` it fixes the error.

```
fsumm = function(data, lookAhead) {
  colnm = sym(glue("abc{lookAhead}") )
  data %>%
    drop_na({{colnm}} ) %>%
    summarise(
      "nPos({{lookAhead}})" := nrow(filter(cur_data(), {{colnm}}>0)), 
      n  = n()
    )   
}
fsumm(df, 2)

#  nPos(2) n
#1       2 5
```

Also, I would actually use `sum` to calculate number of entries that satisfy a condition instead of using `filter` and `nrow`. If we use that then there is no error.

```
fsumm = function(data, lookAhead) {
  colnm = sym(glue("abc{lookAhead}") )
  data %>%
    drop_na({{colnm}} ) %>%
    summarise(n  = n(),
      "nPos({{lookAhead}})" := sum({{colnm}}>0)
    )   
}
fsumm(df, 2)

#  n nPos(2)
#1 5       2
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, you're quite right, it /does/ work.  I have to add another line to the start of the summarise to get it to fail.  ""n({{lookAhead}})"  := n(), " seems to break it.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Yes, that fails outside function as well. First, using `:=` is incorrect for `n := n()` and if you add the line `n = n()` after `"nPos({{lookAhead}})"` it works. I am not exactly sure of the reason though. See the updated answer.

Comment: Blast!  Sorry about the erroneous walrus.  I realised after updating the post that I could simplify the problem, but I tried to do a cut and paste whilst simultaneously dealing with an ankle-biter :).  R didn't complain about it though.

Comment: sum()  is much nicer solution, many thanks.

Comment: rstudio.community suspect it's a bug.  Raised as an issue at https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6138, if you're inclined to see what happens.